# Permutation representations of symmetric group of small order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Thanks for any comments or help.

What is the list of faithful permutation representations of $S_k$ of degree at most $n=2k$ for $k=3,4,5,6$? Is it possible to find its centralizer in each case?

Comment: Professor Holt@ You mean for degree at most $2k$ there exist infinite representation?

Comment: Sorry, no, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do on a computer. For example in magma
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

The following code:

---

for k in [3..6] do
X:=Sym(k);
for n in [k..2*k] do
G:=Sym(n);
for sub in Subgroups(G:OrderEqual:=Factorial(k)) do
H:=sub`subgroup;
if IsIsomorphic(H,X) then
[k,n];
Order(Centraliser(G,H));
end if;
end for;
end for;
end for;

---

will give you all the representations (up to conjugacy in Sym(n)) and the order of the centraliser. It runs in about 10 seconds.

(For example, there are 10 conjugacy classes of Sym(6) in Sym(12), with centralisers of order between 1 and 720.)  If you want more specific information, you can modify the program as needed.

Comment: Of course that gives you the representations up to conjugacy of their images in the symmetric group rather than equivalence classes of representations. For example, $S_6$ obviously occurs only once as a subgroup of $S_6$, but it has two inequivalent faithful permutation representations of degree $6$ (resulting form the outer outer automorphism).